# What is wrong this this code?

Tags: java, swing

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<String> charsToString = new ArrayList<String>();

double tempSmall = 0;
int mainGrade = 0;
Border redLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red), 
        greenLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green);
JLabel grades_Label = new JLabel(" : Normale Arbeiten hier                          Noten durch , trennen !                                Klassenarbeit hier : ");
JLabel output = new JLabel("                                                                                                                                                             Note : ");
JTextField normalGrades = new JTextField(20);
JTextField bigGrade = new JTextField(20);
JButton calc = new JButton("Note berechnen !");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();
}
public MainFrame(){
    super("Noten ausrechnen");
    setSize(1000, 200);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    bigGrade.setBorder(redLine);
    normalGrades.setBorder(greenLine);

    add(calc, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(normalGrades, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(grades_Label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bigGrade, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(output, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    setVisible(true);

    calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 0; i < normalGrades.getText().length(); i++){
                chars.add(normalGrades.getText().charAt(i));    
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++){
                if(chars.get(i).equals("1") || chars.get(i).equals("2") || chars.get(i).equals("3") || chars.get(i).equals("4") || chars.get(i).equals("5") || chars.get(i).equals("6")){
                    grades.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars.get(i).charValue()));
                }else{
                    return;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
                tempSmall += grades.get(i);
            }
            tempSmall /= grades.size();
            output.setText("                                                                                                                                                             Note : " + tempSmall);

        }
    });
}
}
```

The code from line 37 ( calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() )
to line 59 ( the second last } )
does not seem to read the string right...
And I have no idea why...
The code is suppose to convert the string it gets from a normal string to ints
but it does nothing ..
But I also don't get an error ...

Comment: Do you want us to count lines here? Please mark this in your code. Ans please elaborate more on "does not seem to work".

Comment: This code is without imports and stuff. The lines you said is in the code just as it is?

Comment: I'm going to bet that the problem is his `else return` out of the middle of a `for` loop.

Comment: Add a try catch and then paste here the error

Comment: tempSmall /= grades.size(); if grades is empty?

Comment: yeah, hes checking for numbers between 1 and 6... its probably either NAN or not 1-6.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? 1)You don't ensure that it's  executing in the Event Dispatch Thread 2) You unnecesary extends JFrame. 3) You are comparing Strings with Character.

Answer (score 0):

I think that else return; is the line causing the problem. Dry run it for the values and check if you can identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++){
    if(chars.get(i).equals("1") || ...) {
         grades.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars.get(i).charValue()));
    } else {
        return;  ← This line causes the method to terminate
    }
}
```

You should do `chars.get(i) == '1'` in order to compare `char`s.

Also what if `chars.get(i)` is not [1,6]? You do `return;` which causes the method to end. You probably meant to write `continue;` instead (which is like doesn't have an `else`).

Another thing, you should be really careful with

```
tempSmall /= grades.size();
```

You don't seem to handle the case where `grades.size()` is 0 which may crash your program.

Comment: `chars.get(i).equals("1")` wont ever be true - `Char` vs. `String`

Answer (score 0):

Switch this `if` statement:

```
if(chars.get(i).equals("1") || chars.get(i).equals("2") || chars.get(i).equals("3") || chars.get(i).equals("4") || chars.get(i).equals("5") || chars.get(i).equals("6")){
     grades.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars.get(i).charValue()));
}
```

to this:

```
if(chars.get(i).equals('1') || chars.get(i).equals('2') || chars.get(i).equals('3') || chars.get(i).equals('4') || chars.get(i).equals('5') || chars.get(i).equals('6')){
     grades.add(Character.getNumericValue(chars.get(i).charValue()));
}
```

because you're comparing `Character`, not `String`. The `'` instead of `"` makes the whole difference.

Comment: `== '1'` and not `.equals`